# Why do shirt's bottoms "bend" after washing, and how to avoid?

Tags: cleaning, clothing

For 2y now I've noticed my shirt's "bottoms" bending like this:
[image: wrinkles]

(Note that the bottom rolls up)

Why does that happen?
And... How do I avoid it without having to iron them?

Things that I've tried, but didn't work:
Less clothes in washer/drier, fix by hand, hanging them ASAP after dryer, and washing them inside out.

Comment: I've never seen a cotton stockinette shirt (T-shirt type) that failed to do this, unless it had an extended rib-knit on the hem (like the cuffs on long sleeved tee shirts).  It might be a shopping solution.

Comment: This is a natural reaction, I think, as the bottom is double (or triple) the thickness and it's joined with a seem which creates a little pull on the fabric. Could possibly be avoided by removing the bottom seem, but that would induce other more serious features (like the fabric ripping)

Answer (score 3):

It's the heat of the drier - teeshirts don't do this if you hang them up damp, first shaking them out to smooth out the worst of the creases, unkinking any twisted or rolled bits, hanging them bottom down (maybe on hangers or whatever). That's the usual cause, unless you've washed them on a hotter cycle than they can take - teeshirts are best washed around 30deg. It's something to do with the type of cotton they use to stitch them with, often the stitching thread has polyester, or may actually be 100% polyester, so the composition of the main material in the teeshirt against the stitching is different and they react differently to heat. You either need to dry them naturally, or iron them after they've come out of the drier.

Comment: Yes, dry them on hangers, I always do and I don't have this problem at all.